# How to calculate average in mysql with where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: My database table]

Below is my database table.
what will be the sql query to calculate average score of all topic1 entries,of all topic2 entries and so on with where clause(where event_date between this to this)?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: @juergend I tried this. SELECT AVG(score) FROM average_topic_score where topic_name="topic1" AND event_date between '2016-06-03' AND '2016-06-08';

Comment: This is a marked improvement on your previous schema!

Answer (score 1):

use group by

```
select topic_name, avg(score)
from my_table 
where event_date between '2016-03-01' AND '2016-03-31'
group by topic_name
```

Comment: @Strawberry  I presume the event_date is type datetime and the OP use a str for passing the value of the date range

Comment: @Strawberry    explain better  i don't understand

Comment: @Strawberry  thank i'm getting update  for remove the str_to_date .. but you have done before that i finish ..

Comment: @Strawberry I do not speak English so I can make mistakes .. anyway .. I thank you for correcting my answer .. .. I was doing it myself but you've finished first